# how to convert integer to string using typeconverters in room android?

Tags: android-room, typeconverter

I am developing a chat app but I am getting the following error: Cannot find getter for the field.
 that's why I want to convert Integer to String using type converters in Room but I did not find any sample below my User.java model class

```java
     @Entity public class User implements IChatUser {
     @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
     private Integer id;

     @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
     private String name;

     @Ignore
     Bitmap icon;

     public User() {
     }

     @Ignore
     public User(String name, Bitmap icon) {

         this.name = name;
         this.icon = icon;
     }

     @Override
     public Integer getId() {
         return this.id;
     }

     @Override
     public String getName() {
         return this.name;
     }

     public void setId(Integer id) {
         this.id = id;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }

     @Override
     public Bitmap getIcon() {
         return this.icon;
     }


     @Override
     public void setIcon(Bitmap icon) {
         this.icon = icon;
     } }
```

below IchatUser.kt

```
    interface IChatUser {
         fun getId(): String
         fun getName(): String?
         fun getIcon(): Bitmap?
         fun setIcon(bmp: Bitmap) 
      }
```

Comment: The question is incomplete. Can you be more descriptive?

Comment: I am getting error I have posted my question already

Comment: you should post the error also while asking question.

Comment: please check my post

Answer (score 1):

To create a `@TypeConverter` create a java class and call it IntConverter

```
public class IntConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    public static String toString(int number) {
        return number == null ? null : Integer.toString(number);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static int toInt(String str) {
        return str == null ? null : Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
}
```

Now you need the database to know about this TypeConverter so declare this:

```
@TypeConverters(IntConverter.class)
```

Just below the `@Database` annotation in the Database class